# Google Cloud GCP Load Balancer standard tier pricing

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to reduce my k8s GCP load balancing costs for CI/CD purposes, so looking for an explanation of pricing for a Load Balancer in the **standard** tier.  I have read through

https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/docs/overview

and

https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/pricing

but these documents determine pricing by egress $/GB.

From what I understood, a premium tier Load Balancer is priced according to number of configured routing rules.  How would I get billed for Load Balancer in the standard tier?

Answer (score 1):

It is important note that using the standard or premium tier does not affect the price of IP addresses, instances, or forwarding rules. Standard tier pricing is based on source geolocation of traffic and is for [per GB delivered](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/pricing#standard-pricing) that is egress.

I would suggest to take a look at this [help center article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#lb) regarding GCP load balancing and forwarding rules pricing.

Additionally, you can use this [Google Cloud Platform Pricing Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) to estimate the cost of using Google Cloud Platform products, specifically Load Balancer.